# Hashmap replaces values

Tags: java

I am not sure how come hashmap contents are changing.

Below is my code :

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    HashMap<String, Double> map= new HashMap<>();
    map.put("com.x",30.00d);
    map.put("com.y",70.00d);
    map.put("com.z",70.00d);

    List<String> readyServers=new ArrayList<>();
    readyServers.add("system-01");
    readyServers.add("system-02");

    returnServerMapping(2,170.00d,map,readyServers);
}



private static void returnServerMapping(int serverRequired, double totalExpectedExecutionTime,
                                                                   HashMap<String, Double> map, List<String> readyServers) {
    Map<String,List<String>> testSuiteAndServerMap= new HashMap<>();
    List<String> suitesForServer = new ArrayList<>();

    Double executionTimePerServer = totalExpectedExecutionTime / serverRequired;

    int currentServerNumber = 1;
    Double currentTime = 0.0d;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Double t = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(currentServerNumber + " of " + serverRequired + ": " + entry.getKey());
        suitesForServer.add(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println("1.suites:"+suitesForServer);

        currentTime += t;

        if(currentServerNumber == serverRequired){// In the last case, let's get the all remaining suites & finally map this list with the last server
        }else if(currentTime >= executionTimePerServer && currentServerNumber < serverRequired){
            System.out.println("Putting data into the map : server:"+readyServers.get(currentServerNumber-1)+"="+suitesForServer);
            System.out.println("2.suites:"+suitesForServer);
            testSuiteAndServerMap.put(readyServers.get(currentServerNumber-1), suitesForServer);
            suitesForServer.removeAll(suitesForServer);
            System.out.println("3.suites:"+suitesForServer);
            currentServerNumber++;currentTime = 0.0d;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("4.suites:"+suitesForServer);
    testSuiteAndServerMap.put(readyServers.get(serverRequired-1), suitesForServer);
    System.out.println("Final servers & suites:"+testSuiteAndServerMap);
}
```

and the output is

```
1 of 2: com.z
1.suites:[com.z]
1 of 2: com.y
1.suites:[com.z, com.y]
Putting data into the map : server:system-01=[com.z, com.y]
2.suites:[com.z, com.y]
3.suites:[]
2 of 2: com.x
1.suites:[com.x]
4.suites:[com.x]
Final servers & suites:{system-01=[com.x], system-02=[com.x]}
```

So the question is when system-01=[com.z, com.y] then how come it is set to system-01=[com.x] at the end ??

**EDIT**: After debug, I found hashmap contents
Before  suitesForServer.removeAll(suitesForServer); => key-system-01 & value 0-com.z ,  value 1-com.y

After suitesForServer.removeAll(suitesForServer); => key-system-01 & value size=0

**SOLVED** : HashMap was referring to the list. once list contents are changed (at any place), hashmap also modified the contents. To solve this I used a shallow copy which only copied the contents of the list.

```
List<String> suites= new ArrayList<>(suitesForServer);
                testSuiteAndServerMap.put(readyServers.get(currentServerNumber-1), suites);
```

Comment: Debug your program. Then you can see what's happening step by step.

Comment: simplify the code and keep the only part where you think you are having the problem.

Comment: I believe your problem might lie with this : `currentServerNumber-1`
I could be wrong as I didn't test it, but from a glance it seems likely to be the culprit

Comment: `else if(currentTime >= executionTimePerServer && currentServerNumber < serverRequired){` here, you sould not use `>=` for `double` data type. use `(a > b || a-b > 1e-8)` format

Comment: When I debug it, after  suitesForServer.removeAll(suitesForServer); step , hash map has changed for key  : system-01 value is size is 0. before it was 2

Comment: Hint: How many instances of `ArrayList<String>` do you believe you're creating? Remember that the value of in the map will be a reference to the object... you're using the same value again and again.

Comment: The best way for you to understand what's happening at each step of the program would be to step through it with a debugger, checking all the relevant values at each point.

Comment: Your Map is storing reference to ArrayList Object and after that you are modifying the Arraylist object.

Comment: SOLVED !!! Thanks everyone for your inputs. I used shallow copy in my else loop -   List<String> suites= new ArrayList<>(suitesForServer); so this  will copy only the contents of the list, it won't refer to same arraylist

Answer (score 1):

The value of your map is always the same list instance.
After putting the list into the map in your `else` you clear your map via `suitesForServer.removeAll(suitesForServer)`.
I suggest in your `if` you add `com.x` to the list.

In each iteration you should create a new `List` instance:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    List<String> suitesForServer = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Even if I initialize it inside loop, after the loop I wanted to remaining stuff. Instead I used   List<String> suites= new ArrayList<>(suitesForServer); internally in the else loop. This shallow helped hashmap not to refer any objects that are initialized at the top.